# Second Order ODE without $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x(t)''= {a\over x(t)}(x(t)')^2$$
with $x(1) = 1$ and $x'(1) = 1$

Second order Ode without a independent variable + IVP - how would I approach this considering the complexity of the general solution and the fact that it is in terms of $x$?

1. I assumed t=t(x) and then substituted x''(t) with $$ -t''/t'^3 $$ and x'(t). at the end I got $$ t = {A\over(1-a)}x^(1-a)+C $$
   But From there I am unsure how to apply the first order IVP!
   Can't seem to do Mathjax but its x^(1-a)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you add your thoughts and attempts? Please use MathJax. Is it $$x''(t)= \dfrac{a}{x(t)}  (x'(t))^2$$

Comment: Integrate $\frac{x''}{x'}=a\frac{x'}{x}$.

Comment: Are you certain about your initial conditions? They set the solution to be $x(t)=0$.

Comment: Apologies Sal! got the IVP wrong

Answer (score 1):

Since $x(t)$ is on denominator, we search solutions that do not annulate.

Also since $x(1)=1>0$ then $x(t)>0$ for all $t$ and we can set $x(t)=e^{u(t)}$.

Reporting in the ODE we get to $x''=u''e^u+u'^2e^u=\dfrac a{e^u}u'^2e^{2u}\iff u''=(a-1)u'^2$

- For $a<1$ we have:

We can rewrite this $-\dfrac{u''}{u'^2}=1-a$ which integrates into $\dfrac 1{u'}=(1-a)t+c_1$

Then $u=\dfrac{\ln((1-a)t+c_1)}{1-a}+c_2$ and finally adapting the constants for a nicer presentation:

$$x(t)=C\ \sqrt[1-a]{(1-a)(t-t_0)}$$

I omit the details for initial conditions: $t_0=a$ and $C=(1-a)^{2a-2}$ and $x(t)=\left(\dfrac{t-a}{1-a}\right)^{1-a}$

- I let you treat the cases $a=1$ and $a>1$ on your own.

Answer (score 0):

$$x''= {a\over x}(x')^2$$
$$\dfrac {x''}{x'}= a \dfrac {x'} {x}$$
$$(\ln x')'=a (\ln x)'$$
Integrate.
$$\ln x'=a \ln x+C$$
Apply the given initial condition:
$$\implies C=0$$
$$\ln x'=a \ln x$$
$$x'=x^a$$
This should be easy to integrate.